# Data type declaration than allocated size

Tags: c++, c, types

I went through many documents and I still didn't get the size that is used by data types in C especially, maybe the case with all programming language.

Say we have declared a variable like "int = a", we all know the data type “int” has the size of 4 bytes(forget for a moment the arch computer, this is for simplicity) where it can hold values from -2^31 to 2^31 – 1 which is  [0 to 4,294,967,295].

Now the question is, each character or letter or number is stored as 8-bits or a byte, so if int has only 4 bytes as the data types size, how can one store a number like 200,000 or even the max value 4,294,967,295.

There is no concrete document that explains what is exactly the size of the data type.

Comment: It's not being stored as characters, it's stored as a binary number.

Comment: 4 x 8 is 32, so what's your doubt?

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. If you ask about behavior in C then please tag only C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Representation of integers is the same. This is a really general question that spans many programming languages.

Comment: As for the sizes of data-types then there's no guarantee other than `sizeof(char) == 1` and that `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) && sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) && sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long long)`. Also note that even though `sizeof(char) == 1` is guaranteed (by the specification) it doesn't mean that `char` is a single 8-bit byte. There are systems with C compilers where the number of bits might be `7` or `9`. And there are systems where `char` is really `16` bits, but `sizeof(char)` will *still* be equal to `1`.

Comment: You seem to be confusing numbers (or values) with representations. 200,000, "two hundred thousand", and 110000110101000000, can all represent the name number. The last one fits easily in 32 bits.

Comment: Assuming an `int` is represented using four bytes, and each of those bytes consists of eight bits, the total number of bits in an `int` is 32.   Each bit can have two possible settings (e.g. on and off), so the total number of distinct patterns of those 32 bits (each of which represents a value) is 2 to the power of 32.       And, BTW, an `int` is only guaranteed by the standard to be able to represent values between `-32767` and `32767` inclusive.

Comment: You need to read some basic book, explaining binary numbers. When you understand how single byte can store 256 different values, you understand the rest

Comment: "There is no concrete document that explains what is exactly the size of the data type." --> The C spec explains it in detail.

Comment: Alan Birtles - Thanks for the info. Could you please explain what 13-bit numbers mean in 4 byte character. Also does strings and other data types use two's complement? Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

A 4 byte character string can indeed only store numbers up to `9999` or only `999` if you leave space for the minus sign. This is very inefficient though, only storing around 13-bit numbers in 32-bits of data.

Integer data types are instead stored as binary [two's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for signed numbers or simply in [binary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) for unsigned numbers. This uses all the bits allowing storage of `-2^(n-1)` to `2^(n-1)-1` for signed numbers or `0` to `2^n-1` for unsigned numbers where `n` is the number of bits in the number.

Comment: "A 4 byte character string" *without null-terminator*...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if you were going to store numbers as a fixed length string a null terminator wouldn't be necessary, much more efficient to 0 pad on the start of the number

Comment: Alan, C library defines _string_ as including the terminating _null character_.  To use _string_ as in "4 byte character string can indeed only store numbers up to 9999 ...." goes against that, lowering the value of this answer.  Consider "4 byte character _array_ ...".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I never said "a 4 byte C character string"